# How do I set up a VirtualHost for my mail?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, roundcube

I have two files that are loaded by `apache2.conf`:

roundcube.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:3333
```

roundcube.vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:3333>

        DocumentRoot /usr/share/roundcube
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <Directory /usr/share/roundcube>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I know that both files are loaded and parsed by Apache without errors. When I visit the IP address of my VPS with :3333 I'm getting

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 1.2.3.4:3333

I'm getting no errors from Apache or anything, so I suppose that configuration is erroneous. I'm hoping to be able to visit 1.2.3.4:3333 and have `/usr/share/roundcube/index.php` be opened in my browser.

---

iptables

```
root@myservername:~# sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

---

I have added `Listen 3333` right below the `NameVirtualHost` line. It didn't have any effect however. Does order matter when it comes to this? Must for instance `NameVirtualHost` come before or after `<VirtualHost>`? Can the same instance of Apache listen to port 80 and 3333 at the same time?

---

Netstat

```
root@myservername:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# netstat -tulpn | grep -e ':3333' -e ':80' -e ':8080' -e ':443'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7690/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7690/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7690/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7690/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7690/apache2
```

Comment: Can you post the result you get from `sudo iptables -L`?

Comment: I have added them to my question

Comment: What happens in the logs when you hit the page in the browser? Hint: `tail -f  /var/log/apache2/*`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set the Listen directive correctly in your Apache configuration.

`Listen 3333`

[Relevant documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#port)

Comment: I have updated my question. Please look at the bottom. Thanks for your reply

Comment: 3 statements are needed to make this work. Listen 3333, NameVirtualHost *:3333 and <VirtualHost *:3333>. Do you have all 3 in your Apache configuration?

Comment: Yes I do. I still get the same 'timeout' error that I describe in the question. What else could be wrong?

Comment: `Listen 3333` should be on top of the config. Next to `Listen 80` and don't forget to restart the service.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious: you have to restart your Apache before it can listen on the new port. Could you append your question with the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep -e ':3333' -e ':80' -e ':8080' -e ':443'` ?

Comment: @kenny.r: Done. Yes I am restarting Apache after each edit to the configuration. I have put `Listen 3333` at the very top of `apache2.conf`. Can it get any higher than that?

Comment: Netstat shows that Apache is listening on 3333. Looks like you got the configuration part right. The problem is elsewhere.